# How to parse an asset URL in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing

The iPhone `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` returns an URL as:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000001&ext=PNG
```

What's the best (preferably simple) way to retrive `1000000001` and `PNG` as `NSString`s from the above URL example?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can easily turn it into an `NSURL` by using `+[NSURL URLWithString:]`.  From there you could grab the `-query` string and parse it out, something like this:

```
NSString *query = ...;
NSArray *queryPairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *pairs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *queryPair in queryPairs) {
  NSArray *bits = [queryPair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
  if ([bits count] != 2) { continue; }

  NSString *key = [[bits objectAtIndex:0] stringByRemovingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *value = [[bits objectAtIndex:1] stringByRemovingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  [pairs setObject:value forKey:key];
}

NSLog(@"%@", pairs);
```

Warning, typed in a browser, so some of my spellings may be wrong.

Comment: stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Comment: @ohho As of iOS 9, this is deprecated. Use ```[myString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS >= 4.0 you can use native regular expressions with NSRegularExpression class. Examples you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)