# Extract url parameters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse NSURL query property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property)

I have a url like this:

someapp://#access_token=1234%D&refresh_token=54%D%D321&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsf.com

I would like to extract those url parameters to get a dictionary like this:

access_token : 1234=

refresh_token : 54==321

instance_url : https://sf.com

How might I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
NSString *url = @"someapp://#access_token=1234%D&refresh_token=54%D%D321&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsf.com";

NSarray *chunks = [url componentSeparatedBy:@"="]; // OR "?/&/etc"
NSLog("%@", chunks);
```