# Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded NSData into NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, http, urldecode

are there some commonly used utils or standard way to parse http-forms into key-value pairs e.g. into NSDictionary?

thanks for any help

Comment: Could you add a bit of context to your question?  what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to get the values of the http form as it's rendered within a web view, or are you trying to get the values of the form *after* the user clicks "submit" to send the form data back to the server?

Comment: send request from my iOS application to remote server and then receive x-www-from-urlencoded response

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any light-weight solution, but where's good Objective-C library called GCDWebServer

This is how I use it:

in Podfile

```
pod "GCDWebServer"
```

in my application

```
#import "GCDWebServerFunctions.h"

NSDictionary *dict = GCDWebServerParseURLEncodedForm(bodyString);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes. [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html). It's exactly what you're looking for.

UPDATE:

If you need to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys) is best. You may need to first [convert the NSData to a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: it's not about application/json, but application/x-www-form-urlencoded