# $_GET in Objective-C on NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I use PHP's `$_GET` in Objective-C? I would like to use it on an `NSString`:

```
http://baileyseymour.com/QR/data-processor.php?name=John%20Smith&email=example@icloud.com
```

I want to get the value of `name` and/or `email` in the uri.

I want to split the NSString of the URL into 2 parts. `name=John%20Smith` and `email=example@icloud.com`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe your desired result?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I believe he wants a dictionary of the GET parameters, i.e. `@{@"name": "John Smith", @"email: ...}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse URL string to get values for keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use PHP's $_GET in Objective-C? I would like to use it on an NSString:

You cannot. Objective-C is not PHP, so there's nothing to evaluate a PHP symbol in an Obj-C context. If you want to do *something similar*, that's certainly possible but you'll need to describe your situation in a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but here is a short example of how to use `UIWebView` to interact with a PHP document via URL variables.

```
// Objective-C
UIWebView *scoreContent;
scoreContent = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *email = @"you@domain.com";
NSString *webURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"http://yourdomain.com/objc.php?email=%@",
                    email];

[scoreContent loadRequest:
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webURL]]
];
```

Then in the PHP file you could just do something like this:

```
<?php
//objc.php
echo 'Your email is: ' . $_GET['email'] . '.';
?>
```

I would have compiled the Objective-C to make sure it works because I just copied it from a game I made, but if it doesn't work let me know and I'll fix it if you can't.