# What do I use to send user to app from today extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, center, openurl

I am trying to send a user from the today widget to my app. I saw it done using the wwdc demo "creating extensions for iOS part 1" with the clown app demo 22:40 in the video. However, I cannot figure out what to put in the url with string...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"??????"];
        [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        }];
        [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:self.extensionContext.inputItems completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: You most likely want a custom URL scheme.

Comment: How do I create this custom url scheme for an app so that it will direct it to my app?

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459925/integrating-two-login-system-into-an-app/25460458#25460458)