# Swift: Get all key value pairs from a String

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have a `String` which has many key value pairs appended by a `&` sign. i.e: `params = key1=Hello&key2=Hello World&key3=Hi Hello`

Is there a way to extract the values just by passing the keys present in the string? For example I want to extract the value of key1, key2, key3.

Comment: If the *string* is part of an URL take a look at `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem`

Comment: No, It is not a part of an URL. I am receiving an encoded string with just the parameters. After decoding it, I am getting the above string.

Comment: just use [yourString componentSeoratedByString:@"&"]; You will find an array. Now manipulate your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` anyway by creating a dummy URL

```
let params = "key1=Hello&key2=Hello World&key3=Hi Hello"
if let components = URLComponents(string: "http://dummy.com/path?" + params.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!),
    let queryItems = components.queryItems {
    let arrayOfValues = queryItems.flatMap{ $0.value }
    print(arrayOfValues)
}
```

see also [Best way to parse URL string to get values for keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys)

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and got the required results.

Answer (score 3):

```
let string = "key1=Hello&key2=Hello World&key3=Hi Hello"

let components = string.components(separatedBy: "&")


var dictionary: [String : String] = [:]

for component in components{
  let pair = component.components(separatedBy: "=")
  dictionary[pair[0]] = pair[1]
}
```

And in `dictionary` you will get your key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
let params = "key1=Hello&key2=Hello World&key3=Hi Hello"

let separated = params.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&="))
let keys = separated.enumerated().filter{$0.0 % 2 == 0}
print (keys) // [(offset: 0, element: "key1"), (offset: 2, element: "key2"), (offset: 4, element: "key3")]
```

Comment: `index(of:)` is not sufficient because a value which is equal to a later occurring key would break the code. Just use `let keys = separated.enumerated().filter{$0.0 % 2 == 0}` instead, which would also run in O(n) instead of O(n^2).