# How separate my NSString to two different array i.e key and value in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Hello Guys I have one string For example

> "Name=Mihir&,Age=34&,Allergy=&,Symptoms=Fever,Sore
>   throat&,Tested=No&,State=Rhode Island"

So I need to convert this string into 2 arrays key and values like one array before = and another array after equal to.
I have done some code but I don't know what to do next!
Please see my code below:

```
strCustomFields = _incident.CustomFields;
NSLog(@"strCustomFields = %@",strCustomFields);
NSArray *items = [strCustomFields componentsSeparatedByString:@"&,"];
```

Here I have separated into array So now I have 6 arrays but now how to make  my array to key and value like below?
array1 = Name,Age,Allergy,Symptoms,Tested,State
array2 = Mihir,34,,Fever Sore throat,No,Rhode Island

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote the logical code related issue? and that person has downvoted my answer as well. Stackoverflow moderator should verify these kind of upvote and downvote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got my answer may be it's long way to get that but it works for me.

```
NSArray *items = [strCustomFields componentsSeparatedByString:@"&,"];
NSArray *subArr = nil;
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* currentString in items) {
    subArr = [currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    [arr1 addObject:[subArr objectAtIndex:0]];
    [arr1 addObject:[subArr objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSLog(@"subArr = %@", subArr);
}
NSLog(@"arr1 = %@", arr1);  
for (int i = 0; i< [arr1 count]/ 2; i++) {  
            myCustomView.lbltitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:(i *2)]];
            myCustomView.lblvalue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:(i * 2) + 1]];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you may iterate through items ,split each item by '=' and put keys and values in two different NSMUtableArray

but may be it will be better to use NSDictionary to hold key-values pairs

there may be another ways depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Example Please.

Comment: example for NSDictionary ?

Comment: if you trying to parse url parameter string you may take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756683/best-way-to-parse-url-string-to-get-values-for-keys