# How to extract related string using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

For example, I got something format like this:

`link://thisIsAction?param1=value1&param2=value2`

and it may have one param like this

`link://thisIsAction?param1=value1`

or don't have any param:

`link://thisIsAction`

How can I extract the `thisIsAction`, and the `param`, and `value`?
The `param` may not start with the prefix `param`, it may just simple as `p`.

And I want the param and value return in a dict... How can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: I tried using subString... but seems no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"?  I'd say "please post your code and explain what is going wrong", but better answers than fixing it have already been given, but please remember this for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to a NSURL and then use the API to extract different parts of it, including the query string parameters.

You can get the host using

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString]; 
NSString *scheme = [url scheme]; // gives "link" 
NSString *host = [url host];  // gives thisIsAction in your example
NSString *query = [url query]; // gives "param=value1&param=value2"
```

[Documentation on it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

As pointed out by @Rene, to get the query value in a dictionary, follow the top answer on [Parse NSURL query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property)

Answer (score 1):

there's another question, where you could find your answer if you convert it to NSURL first.
[Parse NSURL query property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property)