# Parsing URL Using Regular Expression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

I need to parse a URL in the following format:

http://www.example.com/?method=example.method&firstKey=firstValue&id=1893736&thirdKey=thirdValue

All I need is the value of **1893736** within **&id=1893736**.

I need to do the parsing in Objective-C for my iPhone project. I understand it must have something to do with regular expression. But I just have no clue how to do it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. :)

Comment: URl is not opening correctly...

Comment: Because, it is just an example.

Comment: for what reason you need regex? you can do it with simple functions like `lastIndexOf`, `Substr` and `Split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. You can try something like this

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/?method=example.method&firstKey=firstValue&id=1893736&thirdKey=thirdValue";

NSString *identifier = nil;

for (NSString *arg in [[[url pathComponents] lastObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
  if ([arg hasPrefix:@"id="]) {
    identifier = [arg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id=" withString:@""];
  }
}

NSLog(@"%@", identifier);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**this**](http://regexr.com?31vjp):

```
.*/\?(?:\w*=[^&]*&)*?(?:id=([^&]*))(?:&\w*=[^&]*)*
```

And grap first group: `\1`. You will obtain `1893736`.

#### Simplifying

If the `id` can consist of only digits:

```
.*/\?(?:\w*=[^&]*&)*?(?:id=(\d*))(?:&\w*=[^&]*)*
```

If you don't care about capturing uninterested groups (**[use](http://regexr.com?31vkb)** `\3` or `id` in this case):

```
.*/\?(\w*=.*?&)*?(id=(?<id>\d*))(&\w*=.*)*
```

**[More simpler](http://regexr.com?31vke)** version (use `\3`):

```
.*/\?(.*?=.*?&)*(id=(\d*))(&.*?=.*)*
```

Comment: Why such a strict regex? Surely something like `@".*id=(\\d*)"` would be adequate?

Comment: @Paul.s To ensure it doesn't match other parameters. For example: In a URL such as `http://www.example.com/?pid=1893736&id=123&cid=234` the regex you suggested [will match](http://regexr.com?31vjm) `234`.

Comment: Ok - well then surely this is still much more succinct and now deals with that case `@".*&id=(\\d*)"`

Comment: No, an ampersand before `id` not necessary: `http://www.example.com/?id=1893736`. But, if OP approves that the `id` can consist of only digits, then replacing `id=([^&]*)` with `id=(\d*)` simplifies my regex, as you suggested.

Comment: Ok, `[^&]*&` can be simplified to `.*?&`.

Comment: How about `.*[&\?]id=(\d*).*` - BTW I'm just trying to remove some of the scary for people who aren't that used to regex's

Comment: It matches an invalid URL like `http://www.example.com/&id=1893736`. If all URLs are assumed valid, this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions. Use `NSURL` to reliably extract the query string and then [use this answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410443/573976) to parse the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you can split the string representation of your NSURL instance. In your case, you can split the string by the appersand (&), loop the array looking for the prefix (id=), and get the substring from the index 2 (which is where the = ends).