# Best way to convert NSString key values to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am using a web API and for example it returns:

`access_token=aZDi8ZlmDL34YyxCQt0jXdsRl9Kcinye8r8ilwqCOe3-OII2B96XblSyK7urG4DvPYc&expires_in=1396212623&is_voice_enrolled=false&device_id=3`

So, I need to split up this single string to Key/Value pairs.

access_token:aZDi8ZlmDL34YyxCQt0jXdsRl9Kcinye8r8ilwqCOe3-OII2B96XblSyK7urG4DvPYc

expires_in:1396212623

is_voice_enrolled:false

device_id:3

What is the best way to convert this? Should I split by the `&` and then split again by the `=` sign?

Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially the same question as the following (with the same solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, split on & and then on =, like this:

```
NSString* data = @"access_token=aZDi8ZlmDL34YyxCQt0jXdsRl9Kcinye8r8ilwqCOe3-OII2B96XblSyK7urG4DvPYc&expires_in=1396212623&is_voice_enrolled=false&device_id=3";

NSMutableDictionary* result = [@{} mutableCopy];
[[data componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray* components = [obj componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    result[components[0]] = components[1];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: works great :) thank you for this. This seems more efficient than the way I would have written it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, split by the `&` and then by the `=`.